# Regular expression (PHP)

Tags: php, debugging, expression

Good day, I need to find with a regular expression all matching elements in an array using PHP,  but I have a bug.

```
<?php
$a[0]='user@mail.ru';
$a[1]='112233@mail.domen';
$a[2]='ru@mail.user';
$a[3]='___@.user';
$pattern = '[a-z_0-9]+@[a-z]*.[a-z]{2,}';
for ($i=0;$i<=3;++$i)
{
    if(preg_match($pattern,$a[i]))
    {
        echo $a[i];
    }
}
```

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '+' in {path to file} on line 9

Thanks.

Comment: try to put in double quotes.

Comment: it doesn't matter, which quotes used in regex., but I've tried every variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
$a[0]='user@mail.ru';
$a[1]='112233@mail.domen';
$a[2]='ru@mail.user';
$a[3]='___@.user';
for ($i=0;$i<=3;++$i)
{
  if (!preg_match("/^[-_\.a-z0-9]+@([-_a-z0-9]+\.?)*[a-z]{2,6}$/i", $a[$i])) {
      return false;
  }
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex here -- PHP has a built-in email validation function:

```
filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```

See manual page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

There's even a `filter_var_array()` which will save you from even having to have a loop.

Comment: I just learn and not specifically apply, but thanks for additional information